# FileSystemApiでgetFileが動かない

Tags: javascript, monaca, filesystems

MonacaにてFILEAPIを勉強しているのですが、HPにあるドキュメントを見てもファイルの作成が動きません。
https://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_6.2/file/

こちらのドキュメントを使い、txtファイルを作成しようとした所、getFileが動きません。
OSはiOSで、保存場所にLibraryを使っています。
ファイルの一覧は取得出来ます。
尚、恐らくgetFileの時に、LibraryディレクトリにFileと言うフォルダを作っています。これも何故こうなるか不明です。
初歩的な質問になるかと思いますが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 問題が起きているプログラムのコードを示して下さい。また、ファイルシステムの構成（フォルダーやファイルがどういう構成になっているか）も示して下さい。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
getFileの失敗時に呼び出す引数が間違っていたため、動いていませんでした。
成功時の方ばかり見ていました。
ご迷惑おかけしました。